# How to apply third "if" condition in styleclass?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, css

I have a third apex class Class3 that needs to be applied for a conditional statement in visualforce **Status__c == 'In Progress'**. This is my code.

```
 styleClass="{!IF(account.Status__c == 'Closed','Class1','Class2')}"/>
```

Basically I'm coloring the Status fields according to its value. I have tried with else condition. Doesn't work. Is there any way to fit in the third apex class? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 styleClass="{!IF(account.Status__c == 'Closed','Class1', IF(account.Status__c == 'In Progress','Class2', 'Class3'))}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASE) formula which is a little clearer for this sort of matching:

```
...="{!CASE(account.Status__c, 'Closed', 'Class1', 'In Progress', 'Class2', 'Class3')}"/>
```

Comment: I used the styleClass attribute in <apex:column>. Can I use case as <apex:column value="{!CASE(account.Status__c, 'Closed', 'Class1', 'In Progress', 'Class2', 'Class3')}"/> too? Will be handy :)

Comment: @MnZ Yes you can use this in other places to set `styleClass`. But your comment has `value`: you can use conditional logic for the value too but presumably would not be class names.